# Algorithmic stumper- Need to create a customizable error curve

Tags: c++, algorithm, curve-fitting, curve, model-fitting

First time posting, but this might stimulate someone to think about it.  I am working with a dataset that generates 2 variables that have a polynomial relationship.  Using my data, I have fit the curve to the following code.  I am writing in C++.

```
if (master_key > -300 && (mav[mav.size() - 1] - mav[mav.size() - 2]) < -280) 
           
j_jump = true;

if (master_key > -400 && (mav[mav.size() - 1] - mav[mav.size() - 2]) < -300)
            
j_jump = true;
        
if (master_key > -700 && (mav[mav.size() - 1] - mav[mav.size() - 2]) < -350)
            
j_jump = true;
         
if (master_key > -900 && (mav[mav.size() - 1] - mav[mav.size() - 2]) < -750)
            
j_jump = true;
        
if (master_key > -1150 && (mav[mav.size() - 1] - mav[mav.size() - 2]) < -900)
            
j_jump = true;
        
if (master_key > -1600 && (mav[mav.size() - 1] - mav[mav.size() - 2]) < -1400)
            
j_jump = true;
        
if (master_key > -4000 && (mav[mav.size() - 1] - mav[mav.size() - 2]) < -3000)
            
j_jump = true;
        
if (master_key > -20000 && (mav[mav.size() - 1] - mav[mav.size() - 2]) < -16000)
            
j_jump = true;
```

I have tried to curve fit it with a ton of different algorithms, it does not follow any classic curve.  In essence, (mav[mav.size() - 1] - mav[mav.size() - 2])< X (e.g. -16000) is a probabilistic variable that represents the likelihood of a negative result when above the given X which was determined experimentally. The value of the master key (the more negative the value, the stronger the signal) is proportional to the value of mav.  The more negative mav is, the more positive the master key must be to elicit a positive result.  Any ideas on how to curve fit this would be greatly appreciated.  Ideas as to a method for coding the above if statements into something more succinct would also be appreciated.

Comment: the code is rather unclear. I dont see the 2 variables with a polynomial relationship in there. What is `mav` ? What is `j_jump`? Why do you only ever look at the last two values in `mav` ?

Comment: The code can be more succinct by doing the computation `(mav[mav.size() - 1] - mav[mav.size() - 2])` once, instead of repeating it in every `if` statement. The second thing you can do is put all of the numbers in table, e.g. `int thresholds[8][2] = { {-300, -280}, {-400, -300}, ... }` Then find the correct row in the table for the `master_key` and check the `mav` value.

Comment: If the first condition is `true`, why do you continue to check all the other conditions?

Comment: mav is a trendline (over time)

Comment: if j_jump is true, the program does not proceed, if it is false it does.

Comment: it has to be that both conditions are met. master_key and mav have inverse relationships but not linear.

Comment: thanks for the idea on the table, that will improve that aspect of it.

Comment: @RandenPatterson You need to tag the person you are answering for that person to be able to notice the answer. None of the answers you gave seems to answer my question except perhaps this: "_if j_jump is true, the program does not proceed, if it is false it does_" - but it's wrong. If you set `j_jump` to `true` in the first condition, it will still continue to check all the other conditions.